# How which field is selected on DevExpress grid focus change

Tags: gridview, devexpress, grouping

I'm using the DevExpress grid, and it can be custom grouped by the user.
From the image below, I would like to know, using the GridViewControl_FocusedRowChanged event, when a City row is selected.  In the sample, any Level 1 row.

But if the user changes the grouping to e.g. City -> Country, then I would like to do something when the Level 0 row is selected.

How can I know which Level grouping City is in?

[image]

```
private void GridViewControl_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    bool isCityInFocus = ??;
    if (isCityInFocus)
        //Do Something

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [GetRowLevel](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_GetRowLeveltopic) method:

```
private void GridViewControl_FocusedRowChanged(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Base.FocusedRowChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int level = gridView.GetRowLevel(e.FocusedRowHandle);
    GridColumn column = gridView.GroupedColumns[level];
    bool isCityInFocus = column == columnCity; 
}
```